# ¿Por qué no se borra variable en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este código para abrir una ventana nueva, pasando un código para una factura.

```js
$("#DImprimir").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var Codigo = $('input[name=Infactura_Id]').val();
  $('body').append($('<form/>').attr({
    'action': '/Paginas/Imprimir.php?que=Factura',
    'method': 'post',
    'id': 'replacer',
    'target': '_blank'
  }).append($('<input/>').attr({
    'type': 'hidden',
    'name': 'Codigo',
    'value': Codigo
  }))).find('#replacer').submit();
  var Codigo = '';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

pero por alguna razón al cambiar de factura mantiene la variable `Codigo` y no cambia. ¿que estoy haciendo mal?

quizás una opción seria borrar el form que genera dinámicamente una vez ejecutado
he probado a ponerle un .remove pero sigue igual.

Comment: Hola @Killpe ¿necesitas borrar el valor de el input que viene a través de la variable `Codigo` o necesitas borrar el valor de la variable `Codigo` como tal?

Comment: Pues no se bien @Jorius realmente lo que necesito es que cada vez que se abra la página lea el valor de "infactura_id

Comment: No estás siendo muy claro, trata de dar un ejemplo más acertado, así te podremos ayudar mucho más fácil, tienes una variable `Codigo` que estás redeclarando, pero lo que no sé es si quieres cambiar el valor del `input[name=Infactura_Id]`

Comment: por lo que veo tengo que destruir el append completo que genera dinámicamente el form ¿sabes como destruirlo? @Jorius

Comment: Por que no tratas de pasar algo vació?

Comment: Sigo sin entender que es lo que necesitas :( me frustra no entender y no poder ayudarte

Comment: ya lo he probado y nada. creo que tengo que borrar el form completo para que no lo mantenga ahi. @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos errores.

**Primero**: cuando envías tu formulario no limpias el contenido del input `Infactura_Id`. Sólo redeclaras la variable `Codigo` lo cual no tiene ningún efecto. Solución: restablece el valor del input:

```
$('input[name=Infactura_Id]').val('');
```

**Segundo**, cada vez que presionas `"#DImprimir"` se añade al `body` un formulario con `id = replacer`. La primera vez funcionará, pero de ahí en adelante vas a generar más y más elementos con el mismo ID y eso no debe ocurrir. jQuery no sabrá cuál de esos formularios debe hacerle submit y probablemente seguirá haciéndole submit al primero de ellos.

Solución: elimina el formulario antes de insertar otro.

```
$('body').find('#replacer').remove();
```

Al final, tu código quedaría así (limpié un poco la inserción del form en el body para que quede más claro)

```
$("#DImprimir").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var Codigo = $('input[name=Infactura_Id]').val();
    $('body').find('#replacer').remove();
    var form=$('<form/>').attr({
      'action': '/Paginas/Imprimir.php?que=Factura',
      'method': 'post',
      'id': 'replacer',
      'target': '_blank'
    });
    var input = $('<input/>').attr({
      'type': 'hidden',
        'name': 'Codigo',
        'value': Codigo
      });
    form.append(input);
    $('body').append(form);
    $('#replacer').submit();
    $('input[name=Infactura_Id]').val('');
});
```

Comment: ¡¡Funciona!! Mil graciaaaaas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que succede con tu código es que en esta linea

`var Codigo = $('input[name=Infactura_Id]').val();`

Independientemente de si la declaras de nuevo con `var Codigo = '';`

Seguira teniendo un valor por que tu estas utilizando un selector que toma el valor del elemento input con el atributo `name='Infactura_Id'`, pero estas tomando el primero de todo el DOM, eso significa que si tienes dos form (dos facturas) y quieres imprimir la segunda va a seguir tomando el valor de la primera (como te esta sucediendo), necesitas cambiar tu código para que lea el valor de input de una manera dinámica.

Un ejemplo podría ser seleccionar el valor de input dado la factura que has seleccionado, similar a esto `vat Código = $('form.selected input[name=Infactura_Id]').val();` 
Ahora lo que necesitas es cambiar la clase del form dado si esta seleccionada o no, de esta manera solo tomara el valor del input de una factura si esta seleccionada y no de otras.

Espero que aclare tu problema.